# How to convert PQL query in to JSON?

Tags: json, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I'm trying to convert the below PQL query (Publisher's Query Language) in to JSON format.

```
StatementBuilder statementBuilder =
new StatementBuilder()  
.where("CUSTOM_CRITERIA LIKE '%permutive'")
.withBindVariableValue("orderId", orderId);
```

Can any one help with this ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: do you mean convert the result of the query into json ?

Comment: @rabsom  No . Not the result . But the query can be made in the form of a json file ?